# WIX hides order menu along with other modules any solution?

Tags: wix.com

I want to hide following menu items for specific user role.

1. Store products
2. gift cards
3. reviews

and here is the screenshot.

[image]

after hiding i notice "Orders" also disappear but i dont want to hide it, what should i do?

here is the screenshot

[image]